# Cardinal Arithmetic Property Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

The following proposition is "obvious" but I am having trouble obtaining a rigorous proof of it:
If the set $X$ is finite and $Y$ is a subset of $X$, then $Y$ is finite and #$(Y)\leq$#$(X)$. It is easy to show that if #$(Y)\leq$#$(X)$ then $Y$ is finite, but with regards to proving that #$(Y)\leq$#$(X)$, I have tried a whole bunch of ways to show this given the hypotheses and have come to no satisfactory proof (e.g. I tried a proof by contradiction of assuming #$(Y)>$#$(X)$, but was not able to derive any obvious contradiction).

Comment: Depends on your definition of finiteness. If you define it as a set that is in bijection with some set $\{1,...,n\}$, it is pretty obvious. If you define it as a set that isn't infinite (where an infinite set injects into a proper subset of itself), then you can use proof by contradiction by using the bijection of $Y$ to induce one on $X$. There are many other definitions, too. All depends.

Comment: @Don Thousand, in the book I'm following, a set is said to be finite iff its cardinality is an element of the natural numbers (i.e. $X$ is finite iff #$(X)\in N$, where the natural numbers $N$ are {$0,1,2,...$}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the claim is false. Without loss of generality, this implies that there is some $m,n\in\mathbb N$, $m<n$, such that there is an injection $f$ from $[n]\to[m]$ ($[n]$ is notation for $\{1,...,n\}$).

Also without loss of generality, we can assume that $n$ is the smallest natural for which this property holds.

If $n=1$, the claim is clearly false (you can write out the case yourself).

If $n>2$, let $x_0=1$, and let $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ for all naturals $i$.

I'll leave it to you to prove that if $X=\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$, then $f_X$, the restriction of $f$ to $X$, is a bijection $f_X:X\to X$. Also, note that $X\subset[m]\subsetneq[n]$, so this implies that $f_{[n]\setminus X}$ is an injection from $[n]\setminus X$ to $[m]\setminus X$. This implies that the property holds for $n-|X|<n$, contradicting minimality of $n$.

Comment: That's nice! But so far in the book I'm following (Tao Analysis I), notions of "maximum" or "minimum" have not been defined yet, which makes me presume that Tao does not intend it to be proven this way (and in fact, if you go to his blog and go to the Analysis I page, another reader had asked the same question and Tao had given the hint to "induct on the cardinality of $X$", which caused me to facepalm when I saw it. Anyways, thanks! @Don Thousand.